# Do I need to repour my concrete pier for my deck?

Tags: concrete, deck, support

Good Afternoon,

I spent Sunday digging getting a concrete pier ready for a second story deck I'm putting in. This is my first time pouring concrete and I mixed it to the specifications on the bag. After mixing I shoveled it from my wheelbarrow into the form tube.

As I removed the form tube I noticed that the concrete has a rather rough consistency. This is shown in the following picture.

Please advise. Does this need to be taken out and re-poured? Does this need to be patched? Is this fine as is?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the picture it looks like a surface finish issue only, which should be fine for the structure.

You can skim coat a mortar mix if it will be in a place that's visible.  If it's buried it's not a problem.

Also, the form tubes can actually be left in place if you want and don't have to be removed.

This is caused by air bubbles trapped next to the form. To prevent it you want to vibrate the form while pouring the concrete. Tapping with a hammer works pretty well.  Another tip is to lightly wet the form down with a hose prior to pouring the concrete so the dry form doesn't pull water from the concrete and prematurely dry the edges of the concrete.

I'm slightly concerned about how you plan to connect to the post, normally you would set the post base supports in the wet concrete, you can drill holes to set post supports but this is usually much more difficult.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I also asked our local inspector and he also agrees. He's not worried about it. In regards to the post attachment, I'm using a stainless steel Titen HD.